# Behavior of taxonomy-term classified paths

Tags: 7, views, taxonomy-terms

We have customer who insists that there is a setting/method that will order the listing-page for taxonomy attributed event-type by date ascending. My exploration has lead me to the .../admin/config/search/path/patterns settings in Taxonomy term paths. We are using the default: [term:vocabulary]/[term:name].

However I can not find a setting that will allow for date-ordering. Is there such a setting? The behavior of the site is that the ordering is done by the initial-post date.

I've advised that this can be done w/ View.

Comment: the event date field must be in the view's "Sort criteria" (most likely being the first) and it would be set there. If you need help with this. we need more info and the view being used to produce the event listings page.

Comment: The page I'm referring to is not a VIEW it is -- I believe -- a natively produced page by the taxonomy system.

Comment: Just to confirm this site is in what version of Drupal?

Comment: The site is Drupa 7

Comment: What is the path to the current listing-page that needs to be altered? Out of the box D7 has the path of /taxonomy/term/[taxonomy_term] for display pages that are tag with a taxonomy term. this is built by the function `taxonomy_term_page()` in /modules/taxonomy/taxonomy.pages.inc.

Comment: @littleCoding Thanks for the comments, however I think you are trying to solve the problem w/ code, but what I'm trying to be sure of is that there is or is-not a adjustable "setting" that controls the presentation order of the taxonomy listing-page. I've yet to find one and don't believe there is such a setting.

Comment: If the event listing-page is managed by the default Taxonomy function, there is no UI setting. But if the event listing-page is managed by the Views module (ether its default view for taxonomy or a customized version) then you have the Views UI to be able to adjust the "Sort criteria". Last if there is something else managing the event listing-page we do not have enough information to help just yet.

Comment: hey @LittleCoding,  Thanks that is the answer / confirmation I was looking for.  If you want to submit it as an Answer I can give you credit.

Comment: Sounds good. Sorry it took so many comments. Felt a little too easy to be a full answer.

Answer (score 0):

`/admin/config/search/path/patterns` is an admin page for the module Pathauto, URL alias - Patterns. And the default pattern for Taxonomy terms just happens to be `[term:vocabulary]/[term:name]`.

[image]

You can also see that each "vocabulary" of taxonomy terms can have it's own pattern.

To confirm if Views is handling the display of any of the taxonomy terms pages we need to find a view that takes over the default Taxonomy term path and is already enabled. Meaning, the modules View and Views UI must be enabled. If only Views is enabled, enabling Vies UI at this point makes this easier, plus we will need it later to change the "Sort criteria". With install of the of the Views module the `Taxonomy term` view is created. This view has a path of 'taxonomy/term/%' the same as the Taxonomy modules default path and when the view is enabled it overrides the Taxonomy module's handling of the display of the taxonomy terms pages.

[image]

For a final conformation that this taxonomy vocabulary's term pages are being handled by views lets look at the final HTML that is out generated.

[image]

For a views generated page you will see a few key classes in the content's wrapping elements (unless heavenly custom themed).

```
<div class="content">
  <div class="view view-taxonomy-term view-id-taxonomy_term view-display-id-page view-dom-id-36a8...">
    <div class="view-content">
```

vs the generated page you will see from the taxonomy module.

```
<div class="content">
  <div class="term-listing-heading"><div id="taxonomy-term-1" class="taxonomy-term vocabulary-tags">
    <div class="content">
```

**Bonus tip**: The classes added by the view let us know the machine names of the view being used. `view-id-taxonomy_term` tell you the "taxonomy_term" view is using used, while `view-display-id-page` tell you it is the "page" display in current view.